# Overstay in Germany by mistake

Tags: schengen, customs-and-immigration, overstaying

I went to Germany on business visa (c category) which were valid for 6 months with duration of stay of 15days which I misunderstood for every visit as 15 days and overstayed by 5 days so while leaving the country I was questioned and made to sign papers stating a criminal charge for overstaying ( 95 inr.2 aufentgh )and was allowed to leave the country.now it's been two weeks I haven't received any thing from them yet
I am really in tense situation  now as I don't know the outcome and whom to go for answers .has anyone dealt with a similar situation and what was the outcome. By when do I hear back from the authorities?
 Logged

Comment: http://www.maxi-pedia.com/forum/index.php?topic=865.0

Comment: Everybody in the world overstays by mistake when they get apprehended, but there's really nothing to wait for, the 'outcome' has already happened. Are you asking if they are going to prosecute? No, not for a 5 day breach. Obviously, your visa has been revoked and you do not want to try using it, but those are different questions. Close voting as 'unclear'

Comment: Could you edit to clarify what your question is? Are you asking if there will be any further consequences, for example? I realise that you're probably confused and upset about what happened but it's hard for anyone to help you if we don't know what kind of help you're looking for.